# matplotlib: why inconsistent results between contour and contourf

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, contour, matplotlib-basemap

Why would matplotlib's `contour` and `contourf` produce inconsistent results?

I have some data that I wish to plot on a map using the matplotlib basemap toolkit's stereographic projection. When I plot the data with filled contours, `contourf`, I see the first picture below.  Note the red (positive values) over most of North America.  When I change `contourf` to `contour`, making no other changes, I see the second picture below.  Note the streak of blue (negative values) over central North America.

The `contour` result with the blue is what is actually in the data, and therefore what I expect to see.  The `contourf` result is not what I expect. What could cause this?

[image][image]

The python code is reproduced below. Here `data` is a float32 ndarray of size (73,144), `lon` is a float32 ndarray of size (144,), and `lat` is a float32 ndarray of size (73,). `data` is some NCEP temperature anomaly data evaluated on a 2.5 degree latitude/longitude grid.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# ...read data, lon, and lat from file here...

m = Basemap(width=10000000,height=6000000,
        resolution='l',projection='stere',\
        lat_ts=50,lat_0=50,lon_0=253)
m.drawcoastlines()
lon2d, lat2d = np.meshgrid(lon,lat)
x, y = m(lon2d,lat2d)
mymap = plt.contourf(x,y,data,levels=np.arange(17)-8,cmap=plt.cm.bwr)
plt.colorbar(mymap,orientation='vertical',shrink=0.75)
plt.show()
```

Update: The cylindrical plot produces what I expect with filled contours:
[image]